# Need help scripting a mass conditional formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am running a NFL win/loss pick em and using Google Docs, but the processing of the data is cumbersome so I am working out some scripts to make it flow better.  I have it set to automatically count blue shaded cells for wins and red shaded cells for losses.  My next step is to make it seamless at coding the cells.  I was looking at using this script:

```
function formatting() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var columnO = sheet.getRange(2, 15, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);

  var oValues = columnO.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < oValues.length; i++) {

    if (oValues[i][0] == 'X') {

      sheet.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('blue');
    }
  }
}
```

But I want to know if I can set it to pull the X value from a cell (like I can type Jaguars in cell C13 and have all of my Jaguars cells shaded Blue).  I'm still at the beginning stage of understanding Google Apps Script / javascript, and could definitely use help!  I was using conditional formatting before, but it's cumbersome when there are up to 32 variables to color code.

Comment: This is **not** `Java`. Looks like `JavaScript`.

Comment: Start by knowing the name of the language you're using. JavaScript is not the same language as Java.

Comment: @pnuts: then I apologize.